# Display the website address as text in the toolbar

Tags: android, url, webview, textview, toolbar

I am developing a webview application. When the webview opens a page, I want to display its URL in the toolbar as a text view. But I don't know, please help me...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0kZO.png)

Show Adres site page,in toolbar text view android

Comment: Can you please explain more what exactly behaviour you want? Do you want help in UI ( how to set textview in toolbar) or some help in webview( how to get url from there and set in textview)???

Answer (score 0):

You can use edittext in this way, maybe you can print the site address in the edittext, you can show the page you wrote in the edittext in the webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```